# Can I remove this wall or is it load bearing?

Tags: walls

We want to knock the kitchen and dining room into 1 room and I am hoping someone can help tell me if the highlighted wall is non load bearing:

[image]

Comment: Angled walls like that are not likely to be load bearing. However, the electrical drawing isn't really the one to use to identify this. If you have a structural drawing you could share that would tell us a lot more. Your best bet, however, is _always_ to consult with a structural engineer who will be able to do a hands-on inspection and will be able to give you the sign off you need to satisfy the building inspector and insurance company (should something go wrong).

Comment: Unfortunately it’s the only drawing I have at present. Your comment is appreciated thank you. As the house is a bungalow I suppose would strengthen the case that your initial thought is correct but a structural engineer sounds a safe bet..

Comment: If you have attic access, look at which way the ceiling joists/trusses run. If they run parallel to that wall the answer is _almost_ a guaranteed "not load bearing". If the run perpendicular, the answer is "it depends". A few hundred bucks for a SE to have a look is _far_ cheaper than discovering that the internet sleuths you relied on were wrong, despite their best intentions.

Comment: Also, add the image from your other question to this one. Hit the [edit] button and add it right in.

Comment: I don’t have access to the house for a few weeks yet. But my guess is perpendicular. I’ll get the SE as you say safety first! Thanks for your honest answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, like all "is this wall load bearing" questions, this should only be answered by a licensed SE who can view it onsite.

Comment: We’re not talking about structurally analyzing the Eiffel Tower...this appears to be a single story wood frame house...it’s not that complex. If the op answers a few questions, it should be easy. 1) Is there plywood on either side of the wall? 2) Is there a footing under the wall? 3) Are there roof joists resting on the wall? 4) Is there a post sitting on top of the wall? 5) Does either wall the wall to be removed connects into , extend to the roof joists/ sheathing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Lee Sam. It’s just a stud wall (no ply) I don’t have access to the bungalow just yet so can’t answer much more other than the bungalow is timber frame. The chevron lines either side of wall in question are sleeper walls that run under the length of the bungalow. So not directly below the wall. I should have more details in a few weeks.