# Load bearing or structural

Tags: walls, construction, architecture

We want to knock the kitchen and dining room into 1 room and I am hoping someone can help tell me if the highlighted wall is non load bearing
The house is a bungalow [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I remove this wall or is it load bearing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209219/can-i-remove-this-wall-or-is-it-load-bearing)

Comment: Please edit this picture into your original question instead of asking a new one.